# How do I implement ajax into my jquery to save summernote text into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, summernote

I know that this question has been answered in other places, but they are not as clear as I need them to be for me to understand. I just started programming with Jquery, and I need help implementing some Ajax into a web app. I need to save the values that the user types in the summernote text editor into a database. Can someone show me an example of this with jquery and ajax. I used a textarea for the summernote editor and called jquery to transform it into the editor. I have a save changes button at the bottom of the page, with currently no functionality. When this button is clicked, there should be a function that saves the text. At the beginning of the page, there should be a function that checks if there is any saved text in the database, and it should output it in the editor. If this can be done in ajax, please show me how.

Thanks in advance,

Tommy John

Comment: I'm sorry I could not include the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question without providing the code you have, try to update your question and add your code there,

To answer your question, since you said you're using , here is a simple structure you can use to accomplish your task for the goal of storing the `textarea` value to your database using `jquery, ajax and php`. I dont know what type of data you have, Im assuming your storing text and probably some html tags for styling,

your html:

```
<textarea id='myData'>Some text here I want to save</textarea>
<button type='button' id='saveData'>Save</button>
```

your jquery with ajax:

```
<script>

$(document).on("click","#saveData", function(){
      var myData = $("#myData").text();
      $.ajax({
          url: 'pathToYourPhp file that will receive your post data and will store it to the database',
          type: 'POST', /* Since you are Passing data */ 
          dataType: 'json', /* this is the returned value after saving, you can use text/json/html */
          data: { 'myData': myData }, /* This is the data you are about to store, you can access it on your pathToYourPhp file by using $_POST['myData'], */,
          success: function(data){
             alert('Save'); /* you put here what you want to do after saving */
          }          
      });

});

</script>
```

your php file that will handle the post data:

this is not complete, but this will be the structure of your file,

```
$myData = $_POST['myData'];
```

Your Connection string here

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO yourTable (`fieldName`) VALUES($myData)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. Sorry, I can not provide the code for my project.

Comment: no problem, welcome,